# Custom UIView subClass with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, subclass, target

I am creating a class, that creates an option bar with multiple scroll views accessible by buttons.

This is how I add the subview with its content:

```
NSArray *scroll1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"normal",@"tiltshift",@"zoom",@"normal",@"blur",@"outline",@"coming soon", nil];
NSArray *scroll2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Emoji Natur-01",@"Emoji Natur-02",@"Emoji Natur-03",@"Emoji Natur-04",@"Emoji Natur-05",@"Emoji Natur-06",@"Emoji Natur-07",@"Emoji Natur-08",@"Emoji Natur-09",@"Emoji Natur-10",@"Emoji Natur-11",@"Emoji Natur-12", nil];
NSArray *scroll3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Linear",@"Parallel",@"Parallel 2",@"Crescendo",@"Dubstep",@"Blackhole",@"coming soon", nil];
NSArray *content = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:scroll1,scroll2,scroll3, nil];

[self.view addSubview:[self.bottomOptionView initWithFrame:self.view.frame withContent:content]];
```

The Subclass then generate a scrollview for each Array, with the buttons based on the content of the array:

```
-(void)addScrollViewOfContent:(NSArray*)array{

int viewNumber = array.count;

for (int i = 0 ; i < viewNumber; i++) {

    //create the main buttons
    NSArray *content = array[i];

    UIButton *buttonAccess = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    CGFloat buttonEdge = 40;
    CGFloat buttonSpace = self.frame.size.width /viewNumber;
    int placeOfButton = i+1;
    CGFloat buttonAnchor = ((placeOfButton*(buttonSpace)) - (buttonSpace /2+ buttonEdge/2));
    buttonAccess.frame = CGRectMake(buttonAnchor,  0 , buttonEdge, buttonEdge);

    [buttonAccess setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    buttonAccess.tag = i;
    [buttonAccess addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAccess:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addSubview:buttonAccess];

    UIScrollView *ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    ScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    ScrollView.tag = i;

    ScrollView.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
    ScrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal ;
    //UIImageView *selector = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FILTER_SELECT.png"]];

    CGFloat btnX = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < content.count; i++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(btnX, 2 , 65, 65);

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[content objectAtIndex:i]];
        [button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(subButtonTarget:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        button.tag = i;
        [button setTitle:[content objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Cond" size:15];
        button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines ;         
        button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

        [ScrollView addSubview:button];

        btnX = btnX + 100;

    }

    btnX = btnX - 80;

    ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(btnX + 50, 80);
    ScrollView.hidden = YES;


    [self.scrollViewArray addObject:ScrollView];
    [self addSubview:ScrollView];      
}
```

This gives me exactly what I want.

Then I detect which button, of which scroll view is pressed to trigger the action.

```
-(void)subButtonTarget:(UIButton *)sender{

    int button = sender.tag;
    int scrollview = self.selectedScrollView;

[self.videoEditor subAction:button ofScrollView:scrollview];

}

-(void)buttonAccess:(UIButton *)sender{

    //  self.selectedScrollView = sender.tag;

    for (int i=0; i< self.scrollViewArray.count; i++) {

        UIScrollView *scrollview= [self.scrollViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
    scrollview.hidden= YES;
    }

    int scrollIndex = sender.tag;
    UIScrollView *scrollview= [self.scrollViewArray objectAtIndex:scrollIndex];
    scrollview.hidden = NO;

}
```

Basically when one of the button is touched, it calls a function in the view controller in which the sublclass was initially called.

The problem is that, on touchevent nothing happens, except for `NSLog`. Would that be because of the dependency relation of the subClass and the VC that uses it?

Comment: The problem is that, on touchevent nothing happens, except for NSLog. `NSLog` where it is?

Comment: In the original viewController VideoEditor in the function "subAction".
When I call subAction from VideoEditor whatever is in the function works.
But when I call "SubAction" from the UIView subclass triggered by VideoEditor, then only the NSLog in "SubbAction" is effective.

Comment: Maybe, you should try to add button in the `UIView` first. And then see it works or not. So you can know, where the problem comes from: UIScrollView with buttons or your subclass

Answer (score 0):

You should set this one for each UIScrollView

`ScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;`

And try to subclass `UIScrollView` with override method

```
-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{   
    return YES;
}
```